# TensorFlow Variables and tf.assign() with string

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow , here is a quick question , this is my code

```
session=tf.Session()
x=tf.Variable(str)
valueOfX=session.run(x.assign('xyz'))
print(valueOfX)
```

Why the output is =>

b'xyz'

But when I use int as datatype and assign an integer , the assignment is fine .

Comment: By "the assignment is fine" what do you mean? You get the expected output? Can you show us that please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This confusion arises because Python 3 uses a Unicode string representation for string literals.
The printed representation `b'xyz'` means that `valueOfX` is [a `bytes` object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6269785/3574081). TensorFlow uses `bytes` as the internal representation of all string tensors and variables, and (when using Python 3) implicitly converts `str` literals, such as the `'xyz'` in your code, to `bytes` using a UTF-8 unicode encoding.

Comment: so my output is completely fine ? or there is something which can be done to avoid this 'b' ?

Comment: Yes, it is fine. Assuming that your strings use only ASCII characters, you can disregard the `b` prefix. If you use non-ASCII Unicode characters in your program, you may want to print [`valueOfX.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) instead (and specify the appropriate encoding if you're not using UTF-8).

Comment: thanks, i tried the decoding statement and it works !